# Is it possible to remove the line of a shape using python pptx?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a shape that, when created using `slide.shapes.add_shape`, automatically has a line. Is it possible to remove the line?

I have made the shape 50% transparent and the background behind it is an image which means it's not possible to set the line's colour to blend in.

I was hoping `shape.line = False` would work, but sadly not..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the line fill to no-fill:

```
shape.line.fill.background()
```

This is more reliable, as you mention, than setting the line color so it just doesn't show (most of the time). It has the side benefit that the apparent extents of the shape run to the *actual* edge of the shape, which can prevent subtle alignment issues.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like this works. Using `shape.line.width=0` actually appears to return a shape with a line of width 0.75pt (strangely). But even if you were to set this to 0pt in PowerPoint, a line is still (faintly) visible.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code. This new approach is perhaps a little less intuitive, but models exactly what PowerPoint does when you set the line of a shape to "No line" in the Format Shape property box.